# How do you configure tortoise svn settings for all users in a project?

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

We use subversion to store all our source code. We use Tortoise SVN client to fetch files from the subversion server. A source of common problem across developers is that the "Global Ignore Pattern" settings aren't the same across all developer machines. How do we control propagation of project specific tortoise svn settings across all developer machines (note: all our machines are using the Win XP OS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store svn:ignore with your project. Right-click on the folder, choose Properties, then select Subversion tab, then click Properties... button, on the next dialog press New... Choose svn:ignore from the dropdown and enter all items on separate lines:

*.suo

*.user

bin

Comment: I also used the recursive option and stored all the affected folders in subversion.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're misusing the global ignore pattern feature -- it should really be used for things that are developer-specific.  Use the svn:ignore property instead, that way it's stored in the repository.  I know that it's a pain having to set it on every directory :(.

In Tortoise, you can add files and directories to the ignore list by right-clicking on them and picking "Tortoise SVN"->"Add to ignore list" then deciding whether you want the wildcard or the specific filename.

Comment: "It's a pain having to set it on every directory".  Luckily TortoiseSVN can apply properties recursively :)